# Weather API and JSON

Tags: javascript, json

So,I am trying to use the Open Weather API: http://openweathermap.org/current

Here is my javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {



if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    $(".ok").html("latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + "<br>longitude: " + position.coords.longitude);
    var ur="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat="+position.coords.latitude+"&lon="+position.coords.longitude+"&appid=18c7e2b6b0150a8f1d2c6b946e065697";
        $.getJSON(ur, function(json) {
        $(".ok2").html(JSON.stringify(json));


        alert(json.weather[main]);

        });

  });
}
});
```

Here is the expected output:

```
{"coord":{"lon":139,"lat":35},
"sys":{"country":"JP","sunrise":1369769524,"sunset":1369821049},
"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04n"}],
"main":{"temp":289.5,"humidity":89,"pressure":1013,"temp_min":287.04,"temp_max":292.04},
"wind":{"speed":7.31,"deg":187.002},
"rain":{"3h":0},
"clouds":{"all":92},
"dt":1369824698,
"id":1851632,
"name":"Shuzenji",
"cod":200}
```

The output is displayed correctly in my test page but  the alert(json.weather[main]); doesn't work and I want to know how can I access the particular keys of my JSON Object.For example if I want to access the id shouldn't the following do it for me: json.id; ?

Comment: Hint: `json.weather[main]` in this expression why do you use `.` and `[]`? Do you understand the difference?

Comment: @zerkms Isn't json an object though?I am trying to access the key-value pair.

Comment: You haven't answered my question: do you understand the difference between using `.` and `[]`? Why did you use `.` in one case, and `[]` in the other?

Comment: @zerkms Isn't it the same?

Comment: It is not. Otherwise I would not ask it twice.

Comment: @sterg For future questions, don't just say "x doesn't work"; provide any error messages from the JS console or elsewhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**json.weather** is an array:

```
json.weather = [{"id":804,"main":"clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04n"}]
```

An array is a container object that holds a number of values of a multiple types in ***Javascript***, to access these values you must specified ***Integer*** index.

```
json.weather[0] = {"id":804,"main":"clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04n"}
```

**json.weather[0]** is an ***Javascript Object*** and you must specify the property name,
you can access the properties in two ways:

- jsonObject["propertyName"]
- jsonObject.propertyName

## So

Just change this:

```
alert(json.weather[main]);
```

With:

```
alert(json.weather[0].main);
```

Comment: "*json.weather[0] is an JSON object "* No, it's a JavaScript object.  [There is no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: Thanks @FelixKling

Answer (score 0):

You can access a property of an object in JavaScript in two ways. First, using dot-notation:

```
object.property // after the dot, literally write the name of the property
```

and second, using brackets:

```
object["property"] // in the [], put any expression
```

Brackets take any expression, and use the value of that expression as the name of the property to access. So writing `weather[main]` first evaluates the expression in the brackets: `main`. This is a variable name, so it will evaluate to the value of the `main` variable (or, if `main` doesn't exist, will throw an error).

**If you want to access a property with a fixed name, you should generally use dot-notation. So `alert(json.weather[main]);` should be `alert(json.weather.main);`.** Simple as that.

Brackets are used when the name of the property to be accessed either (a) isn't a valid identifier, e.g. contains special characters, or (b) isn't fixed, e.g. depends on variables or such.

Comment: "or, if `main` doesn't exist, undefined" --- it actually will be an error

Comment: Good catch, edited